# Angular2 table rows animation

Tags: angular2-template, angular-animations

I have a table which its rows creates by collection, like this plnkr -

[example](https://plnkr.co/edit/dqD9BKB8mCv9PCDWegPk?p=preview)

and this code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let element of elements">
      <td>{{element.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  `,
})
export class App {
  elements:any;

  constructor() {
    this.elements = [
      {name:"name1"},
      {name:"name2"},
      {name:"name3"},
      {name:"name4"}
      ];
  }
}
```

I want to add animation each time the order of the rows changes that show the row moves to the new place.
I tried to add index number as animation state but I don't know how to make the animation between them, how can I do it?

Comment: The builtin snippet tool don't work with angular2. Do you know how to solve the question?

Comment: Nevermind, that was my fault.